# Windows file search within a search, how? App, script, GREP, powershell, notepad hack?

Tags: powershell, search, grep

I am trying to search for folders created within a certain date range, then search for files with certain attributes in only those folders. I thought with Windows 8's "advanced query system" this would be a 2 minute job...it isn't!

Can anyone recommend an easy way to do this? I'm thinking along the lines of regular expressions i can input into AstroGrep, or a Notepad++ hack, as it's easy to copy folder paths from windows search into a text document.

Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, I am trying to find files which were added to the system during a certain date range. Searching by file created/modified attributes does not help as these attributes are carried over when the file is moved. However a folder's date attributes do change when files are moved in and out. Therefore I need to search for folders by date, then (because of the huge number of files and subfolders) search within the resulting folders for my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmldet to retrieve all directories during a certain date range (for example: *Now* and *a Month ago*):

```
$dateNow = Get-Date
$dateaMonthAgo = $dateNow.AddMonths(-1)

$directories = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Directory -Recurse | 
    Where { $_.LastAccessTime -le $dateNow -and $_.LastAccessTime -ge $dateaMonthAgo }
```

Now you have all directories that matches the date range. You can iterate over them and search for your files:

```
$directories | Get-ChildItem -Filter 'yourFile.txt'
```

Comment: Brilliant! I substituted _.LastAccessTime for _.CreationTime and it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to use get-childitem to return the full paths of the files? As opposed to the directory/column view? I tried using the -name parameter which gives a basic list of the filenames with extensions, but no paths.

Comment: Of course. Just `select` the `FullName` property: `$directories | Get-ChildItem -Filter 'yourFile.txt' | select FullName` Note: If you don't want the header, add a `-expand` after the select. Please consider accepting the answer :-)

Comment: With |Out_File to send the paths to a text file, this is exactly what I needed.  Don't know why I couldn't find a GUI file search program with this kind of iterative searching, surely anything that narrows down search results is useful to a lot of people.